# Auto function call receiving and updating field in Titanium/android

Tags: android, tcp, client-server, titanium

I have a tcp callback function written in config.js and included it into my index.js file using

```
Titanium.include('config.js');
```

I just want whenever this callback invoked by some client, a textfield in index.js should be updated accordingly the data it receives from function no matter on what screen we are it should update field in backend.I tried many ways but couldn't succeeded.Please Help and guide.

Ali

Answer (score 1):

create a custom event in config.js and fire it whenever you want